# What is the best practice for having a global collection or set number?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am setting up a content type for a collection of samples. There is already a lot of samples that have a collection number that can't be changed, so I will have to import that data. But My question is how to apply this number; I know its a broad question, but would using taxonomy, or a field in the content type be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field would be better if the collection number must be unique. If so you can activate the [Unique Field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) module to enforce it, then go ahead and import your existing data.

If it does not have to be unique, either will work, but I would still recommend using a text field rather than a taxonomy.

Comment: Awesome this great. Someone also suggested tying it into the node number. So if say we had a collection number of 5000, we have that piece of content at 5000 + some number of nodes used for other things. But I think I might try unique field first/. Thanks for the tip!